# sharing browsing session and history over multiple machines

Tags: browser

I browse a lot at office. And do the same at home. Is there anyway so that I can combine both sessions, both history and open pages. ie, whatever I accessed from home should be visible at office, and whatever I accessed from office should be visible later at home. I prefer chrome and firefox, but a solution in any browser would do good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Google Chrome Sync

In Google Chrome, this is built in: click on the tools button (upper right-hand corner) and click "Set up sync". It will save your bookmarks, preferences, history, etc. with your google account, and then sync it anywhere you log in and click that button.

[image: sync]

## Firefox Sync Addon

Firefox has an official addon to do this; you can download [Firefox Sync](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10868/) from the addons site.

Comment: Lol, thanks for copying my answer into yours... :P

Comment: Whoa, I actually didn't see your answer. I knew about Chrome Sync because I use it, and then after I'd posted it, thought "hm, I bet there's a firefox addon to do this, I'll go look", so I checked on addons.mozilla.org, and there it was. I guess I was reading your mind/you were reading mine and we just didn't realize it :P

+1 to you for accidental brain reading ;)

Comment: yeah , but does it support syncing history too?

Comment: I'm not sure myself, having not used the firefox one, but BloodPhilia may be able to provide some insight there. Or, just try it out and see ;)

Answer (score 2):

in Addition to nhinkle's answer: For Firefox, you might consider using Firefox Sync, which is an official add-on for Firefox.
http://www.mozilla.com/en/firefox/sync/

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can use also Xmarks at xmarks.com. It is supporting multiple browsers.